# On the non-zero elements in $H^*(\mathbb{C}P^4/\mathbb{C}P^2; \mathbb{F}_2)$

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, homotopy-theory

The following is an attempt to prove that $x^3$ and $x^4$,respectively, are the non-zero elements in the cohomology groups $H^6(\mathbb{C}P^4/\mathbb{C}P^2; \mathbb{F} _2)$ and $H^8(\mathbb{C}P^4/\mathbb{C}P^2; \mathbb{F}_2)$. It is imperative to verify the validity of this argument and I welcome any alternative approaches.

The inclusion map $i: \mathbb{C}P^2 \hookrightarrow \mathbb{C}P^4$ induces a restriction map $i^{*}: H^\bullet(\mathbb{C}P^4; \mathbb{F}_2) \to H^\bullet(\mathbb{C}P^2; \mathbb{F}_2).$ Then, in any even degree, we have a short exact sequence
$$ 0\to H^{2n}(\mathbb{C}P^4/\mathbb{C}P^2; \mathbb{F}_2)\to H^{2n}(\mathbb{C}P^4; \mathbb{F}_2)\to H^{2n}(\mathbb{C}P^2; \mathbb{F}_2)\to 0.$$
On the other hand, as is known, $H^*(\mathbb{C}P^4; \mathbb{F}_2) \cong \mathbb{F}_2[x]/\langle x^5\rangle,\, x\in H^2(\mathbb{C}P^4; \mathbb{F}_2);$ further
$$ H^k(\mathbb{C}P^n; \mathbb F_2) = \left\{\begin{array}{ll} \mathbb F_2 &\mbox{if $0\leq k\leq 2n,$ and $k$ even},\\
0 &\mbox{otherwise}.
\end{array}\right.$$
Hence by the above short exact sequence, one has the isomorphisms: $H^{6}(\mathbb{C}P^4/\mathbb{C}P^2; \mathbb{F}_2)\cong H^{6}(\mathbb{C}P^4; \mathbb{F}_2)$ and $H^{8}(\mathbb{C}P^4/\mathbb{C}P^2; \mathbb{F}_2)\cong H^{8}(\mathbb{C}P^4; \mathbb{F}_2).$ Thus, under these isomorphisms in combination with the fact that $x$ is the generator of $H^2(\mathbb{C}P^4; \mathbb{F}_2),$ it follows that $x^{3}$ and $x^{4}$ are sent to the non-zero elements of $H^6(\mathbb{C}P^4/\mathbb{C}P^2; \mathbb{F}_2)$ and $H^8(\mathbb{C}P^4/\mathbb{C}P^2; \mathbb{F}_2)$, respectively.

Remark: Owing to $x\in H^{2}(\mathbb{C}P^4; \mathbb{F}_2),$ the Cartan formula yields the following expression:
$$ \begin{array}{lll}
Sq^2(x^3) 
& =&Sq^0(x^2)\smile Sq^2(x) + Sq^1(x^2)\smile Sq^1(x) + Sq^0(x)\smile Sq^2(x^2)\\
&=& Sq^0(x^2)\smile Sq^2(x) + Sq^1(x^2)\smile Sq^1(x) + Sq^0(x)\smile (Sq^{1}(x))^{2}\\
&=&x^{2}\smile x^{2} =   x^{4}\neq 0\ \ \mbox{(since $Sq^1(x)\in H^{3}(\mathbb{C}P^4; \mathbb{F}_2) = 0$)}.
\end{array}$$
This leads to a non-trivial homomorphism $$Sq^2: H^6(\mathbb{C}P^4/\mathbb{C}P^2; \mathbb{F}_2)\to H^8(\mathbb{C}P^4/\mathbb{C}P^2; \mathbb{F}_2).$$

Comment: What is $x$? Do you really mean $i^*(x)=y^2$, rather than $i^*(x)=y$?

Comment: @John Palmieri We see that $i^*$ is the induced map on cohomology by the inclusion map $i:\mathbb{C}P^2\to\mathbb{C}P^4$, which sends the generator $x\in H^2(\mathbb{C}P^4;\mathbb{F}_2)$ to its restriction $i^*(x)\in H^2(\mathbb{C}P^2;\mathbb{F}_2)$.

Since $y^2$ generates $H^4(\mathbb{C}P^2;\mathbb{F}_2)$ and $i^*(x)$ is a degree $2$ cohomology class in $\mathbb{C}P^2$, it must be a multiple of $y^2$. Since $i^*(x)$ cannot be equal to $0$ (because $x$ generates $H^2(\mathbb{C}P^4;\mathbb{F}_2)$ and $i$ is an injection on cohomology), it follows that $i^*(x)=y^2$.

Comment: @John Palmieri  May I inquire as to the validity of the aforementioned argument? If you possess an alternative viewpoint, kindly provide additional details for consideration

Comment: If $x \in H^2(...)$, then $i^*(x) \in H^2(...)$: induced maps on cohomology preserve dimension. So if $x \in H^2(\mathbb{C}P^4)$, then $i^*(x)$ should be a multiple of $y \in H^2(\mathbb{C}P^2)$.

Comment: Note also that your original post doesn't define $x$.

Comment: @John Palmieri Here $H^*(\mathbb{C}P^4; \mathbb{F}_2) \cong \mathbb{F}_2[x]/\langle x^5\rangle.$ By substituting $i^*(x) = y,$ the arguments in the original version remain unaffected, correct?

Comment: @John Palmieri I have made some revisions to my original post.

Comment: It would be good to state what exactly you're trying to prove. You want to know about the validity of an argument, but an argument trying to establish what?

Comment: @John Palmieri The primary objective of this post is to present an argument demonstrating that $x^3$ and $x^4$ are the non-zero elements of $H^6(\mathbb{C}P^4/\mathbb{C}P^2; \mathbb{F}_2)$ and $H^8(\mathbb{C}P^4/\mathbb{C}P^2; \mathbb{F}_2)$, respectively. Here $H^*(\mathbb{C}P^4; \mathbb{F}_2) \cong \mathbb{F}_2[x]/\langle x^5\rangle$, where $x\in H^2 (\mathbb{C}P^4; \mathbb{F}_2)$.  May I ask if you have an alternative method of proving the aforementioned assertion?

Comment: @John Palmieri I have made some revisions to my original post. Could you please help me determine whether the argument in question is flawed or not? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your argument is flawed. You claim that $x^3$ is in the image of $\delta$, but it's not. The long exact sequence looks like
$$
\cdots \to H^5 \mathbb{C}P^4 \to H^5\mathbb{C}P^2 \xrightarrow{\delta} H^6 \mathbb{C}P^4 / \mathbb{C}P^2 \to H^6 \mathbb{C}P^4 \to H^6 \mathbb{C}P^2 \to \cdots
$$
Most of the terms here are zero:
$$
\cdots \to 0 \to 0 \xrightarrow{\delta} H^6 \mathbb{C}P^4 / \mathbb{C}P^2 \to H^6 \mathbb{C}P^4 \to 0 \to \cdots
$$
So no nonzero elements are in the image of $\delta$. Perhaps more usefully, though, there is an isomorphism
$$
H^6 \mathbb{C}P^4 / \mathbb{C}P^2 \cong H^6 \mathbb{C}P^4.
$$

More generally, all of the odd-dimensional cohomology groups are zero. In any even degree, you get a short exact sequence
$$
0 \xrightarrow{\delta}  H^{2m} \mathbb{C}P^4 / \mathbb{C}P^2 \to H^{2m} \mathbb{C}P^4 \to H^{2m} \mathbb{C}P^2 \to 0,
$$
either the left term or the right term is zero, depending on the dimension.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding your revised argument:

(a) You need to define $x$ before discussing $x^3$ and $x^4$.

(b) Your first sentence says, "The following is an argument regarding the non-zero elements $x^3$ and $x^4$, respectively, in the cohomology groups $H^6(\mathbb{C}P^4/\mathbb{C}P^2; \mathbb{F} _2)$ and $H^8(\mathbb{C}P^4/\mathbb{C}P^2; \mathbb{F}_2)$." So you're already asserting that these are the nonzero elements. I thought that this was what you were trying to prove, so you should not assert it. Perhaps instead something like, "The following is an attempt to prove that $x^3$ and $x^4$, respectively, are the non-zero elements in ..."

(c) Furthermore, it is sloppy to say that $x^3$ is the nonzero element in $H^6\mathbb{C}P^4/\mathbb{C}P^2$: $x^3$ is instead an element of $H^6 \mathbb{C}P^4$, and the argument shows that $H^6 \mathbb{C}P^4 \cong H^6\mathbb{C}P^4/\mathbb{C}P^2$. Under this isomorphism, $x^3$ is sent to the nonzero element of $H^6\mathbb{C}P^4/\mathbb{C}P^2$.

($H^*\mathbb{C}P^4/\mathbb{C}P^2$ is a ring, but the nonzero element in $H^6 \mathbb{C}P^4/\mathbb{C}P^2$ is not the cube of any element in that ring, so it should not have the name "$x^3$".)

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I have made the necessary revisions to my post, incorporating your feedback. Additionally, I have included a remark and would appreciate your thoughts on it.

Comment: Your remark is almost correct. The only error is that $Sq^2(x^2)=0$. (Use the Cartan formula.) This doesn't affect your conclusion.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. I have taken your comment into consideration and made the necessary amendments to my original post.

Comment: I would like to ask for your opinion on a matter that, by utilizing the tools of Mayer-Vietoris sequence and Universal Coefficient Theorem, we can get the result:
$$ H^k(\mathbb{C}P^4/\mathbb{C}P^2; \mathbb{F}_2)\cong H^k(\mathbb{S}^6\vee \mathbb{S }^8; \mathbb{F}_2) = \left\{\begin{array}{ll} \mathbb F_2 &\mbox{if }k = 0, 6, 8,\\
0 &\mbox{otherwise}.
\end{array}\right.$$

Comment: Is this true for any ring R? i.e.,
$$ H^k(\mathbb{C}P^4/\mathbb{C}P^2; R)\cong H^k(\mathbb{S}^6\vee \mathbb{S }^8; R) = \left\{\begin{array}{ll} R &\mbox{if }k = 0, 6, 8,\\
0 &\mbox{otherwise}.
\end{array}\right.$$

Comment: Sure, that's true for any ring.

Comment: I have noticed that let $\mathbb CP^{n}$ denotes the complex projective space with real manifold dimension $2n.$ Then, $\mathbb{C}P^{n}/\mathbb{C}P^{n-2}\not\simeq \mathbb{S}^{2n-2}\vee \mathbb{S}^{2n}$ if $n$ even, while $\mathbb{C}P^{n}/\mathbb{C}P^{n-2}\simeq \mathbb{S}^{2n-2}\vee \mathbb{S}^{2n}$ if $n$ odd.

I am uncertain about the validity of the above result. Given your expertise in algebraic topology and homotopy theory, I would greatly appreciate hearing your opinion on the matter. Additionally, I believe that Steenrod operators may be employed as a tool in proving that result.

Comment: I would greatly appreciate receiving your expert feedback and analysis regarding the above-mentioned result.

Comment: You should open up another question on this site.